# In GraphQL, how does the operator `lt` and `gt` work?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

In Gatsby, when we make a query with the `lt` or `gt` operator on a date of type `mdx` does it return the closest "greater than" or the closest "less than"?

I've done some quick experimentation and does look like it does, but could not find any official documentation on GraphQL or on Gatsby to explain exactly how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the official documentation here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#complete-list-of-possible-operators

So yes, `lt` is "less than", `gt` is "greater than". As you can also see there two more variants of this exist:

- `lte` "less than or equal"
- `gte` "greater than or equal"

But it doesn't return the "closest" result as you'll be filtering the result with this. So you will get multiple results if they exist.